# jQuery Simple Slideshow on click issue

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am trying to create image slideshow using jQuery. I have **4 photos**, a **previous button** and a **next button**. The previous and next button are working and they are moving the images -=400px and +=400px. However i would like when i am at the first photo and the user clicks on previous button to take him to the last photo, and if the user is at the last photo and clicks the next button to take him to the first photo. Hopefully someone can help with the issue

Thanks.

HTML code:

```
<div class="images">
        <div class="images_inside">
            <img src="imgs/model_01.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_02.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_04.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_05.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.images {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images_inside {
    width:1600px;
    height:400px;
}

.images img {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(".next").on("click", function(){
    var $a = $(".images .images_inside").css("margin-left", "-=400px");
});

$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    var $b = $(".images .images_inside").css("margin-left", "+=400px");
});
```

Comment: P.S: I'd suggest you to use CSS3 transitions instead of `left` or `margin` properties. it's faster and smoother. Also in your code there's no means to do `var $a` and `$b` those variables are unnecessary.

Comment: Yea i could remove the a and b variables. I just put them for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math involved is quite simple,
Calculate the `tot` number of slides and use a `counter`

```js
var $gallery = $(".images_inside"),
    tot = $("> *", $gallery).length,
    counter = 0;

$(".prev, .next").on("click", function() {

    // Increment/decrement the counter depending on the clicked button:
    counter = $(this).hasClass("next") ? ++counter : --counter;
    // Let's fix the counter loop
    counter = counter<0 ? tot-1 : counter%tot;

    // Finally ainmate your gallery using CSS!
    $gallery.css({
        transition: "0.5s",
        transform: "translateX(-"+  (100*counter)  +"%)"
    });

});
```

```css
.images {overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-size:0;}
.images_inside>* {width: 100%;display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div class="images_inside">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400x80/cf5?text=1">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400x80/f5c?text=2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400x80/5ff?text=3">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400x80/fc5?text=4">
  </div>
</div>
<button class="prev">&larr;</button>
<button class="next">&rarr;</button>
```

*[**jsBin demo (compact code version)**](http://jsbin.com/moxolo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)*

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global JS variable you can update to let you know which image the user is currently on. Then in your `on click` function look at the variable and if you are on the first image and you click previous, update the margin differently to jump to the last image. Same for the next button on the last image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nived but is it possible to type the code please?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you're quite fresh with jQuery.

The way you're trying to achieve this is wrong even if you will make it to work.

I would suggest you to take a look at [this website](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/jquery-image-galleries/) and use some jQuery plug-in.

The website also has different examples how to achieve it yourself at the bottom.

Comment: Please, the question is quite specific (although a little bit broad?) but suggesting a link is not in the expected format, can you please put some small code? There's a specific nifty trick to loop images (counter) using prev- next actions, would be nice to see this answer improved!

Comment: Thanks Gintas K for the website. I dont want to use any plugins. I will check the website though to see if ill find any good examples.